# How to get a post's title in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working in WordPress, and I need to show the post's title and description in a loop.

I don't know how to get the post's title and its description.

My current html code is below:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="single-service-home">
        <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="inner-box">
                <i class="flaticon-gesture-1"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Charity For Education</h3>
            <p>There are many variations of lorem <br>passagei of Lorem Ipsum available <br> but the majority have </p>
            <a href="service-details.html">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code inside `<h3>` tag I need to show the title and in `<p>` tag I need to show the description.

Also in read more I need to give that post's detail page link.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display post title in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579335/how-to-display-post-title-in-wordpress) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792123/how-to-get-post-title-in-wordpress

Comment: none of the above helped. it only displays the current page title. I used `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>` please clarify

Answer (score 2):

You need to start with [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). The WordPress docs have loads of info with examples. The loop is a snippet of standard PHP code that sets up the current post data in your template and allows you to use all the standard template tags for each post (or page).

The loop is basically this:

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    //
    // HTML & any template tags go here.
    //
endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Once you've set up "the loop", you can easily echo out things like [the title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title), [the permalink](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink), and loads of other template tags.

For example, this is common:

```
<?php // Open the loop
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <h1>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </h1>
  <div class="content"><?php the_content();?></div>
  <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>

<?php // End the loop
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

You'll also need to make sure the rest of your template is set up correctly, using [get header](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) and [get footer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer).

When it comes to WordPress, just Google it. It'll be answered already somewhere, and the WordPress docs are the place to start. For example, search "Wordpress show title" and you'd get the info you need.

Comment: Thank you so much t-jam.. I also tried searching for the solution.. but when used the code It is returning only the page's title instead of post title. please help

Comment: I used this code `<h3><?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
 <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: So you have a page and you're wanting to display other posts on it, like an index page?

Comment: yes.. I have set up a template for home page and included header and footer in it... Now I just want to show the posts in that page.. wherever I used `the_title`.. it returns only the page's title instead of post's title..

Comment: OK, so that's a different question that what you've asked. In that case, you need a secondary loop. You're not just wanting to show the title of the page you're on, you want to fetch content from other posts - that's outside the function of the loop. Either you can set up a new wp_query targeting the post type you want to loop through, or you can set your home page to the 'page for posts' in the WordPress admin, allowing you to use it as a post index.

Comment: yes.. instead of the page title, I just want to show the available posts.. their title and description.. maximum 6 posts in that page..

Comment: You can use something like this after your first loop to show a different type of post in a second loop: https://gist.github.com/milohuang/5708580. Note that this example uses "post_type=news". You may want "post" instead of "news".

Comment: Have a look on the WordPress codex for the standard index.php template. This may be what you want. Another suggestion if you're just starting out is to use a theme starter, otherwise you'll likely run into all sorts of issues.

Comment: yes t-jam.. now it returns the post's title.. now I need to figure out how to adopt it to the design and display based on the loop.. thank you so much for your help.. I will also check the wordpress codex.. thanks